# WordPress wp_nav_menu - add title value with <span> into <a>

Tags: wordpress, function, menu, addition, nav

default:

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="...">首页</a></li>
  ...
</ul>
```

I want to add title value with [span] into [a].

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="...">首页<span>HOME</span></a></li>
  ...
</ul>
```

[title value](http://i.min.us/idWpVc.png)

Answer (score 3):

```
<?php $args = array(
  'link_before'     => '<span>',
  'link_after'      => '</span>'
);
?>

<?php wp_nav_menu($args); ?>
```

Include in args array [other parameters](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu) that you need.

Comment: This is indeed correct. This was not clear in the WP codex despite reading it once all the way through. Thanks for the help!

Comment: it added the span tag, but no way to add title vaue.